# Need to change status bar height for iphone X

Tags: ios, iphone, statusbar

For all other iPhones, the status bar height is 20.0f and for iPhone x status bar height is 44f. I want to change status bar height of iPhone x. I am able to programmatically get the status bar height.

But is it possible to change its height in any way?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Apple provides its standard layout and developer have to  develop their app according to apple rule. And by the way before doing any experiment first read about safeArea.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the height of the status bar yourself. The best you can do is hide it:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController{
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        get{
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can adjust your layout based on its height, which you can get like this:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
```

Comment: OP already getting height of status, read the quess again. Its all about either he can change the height of status bar or not.

Comment: I understand that, and I responded to that. I also put the line to get the height current here, in case others who see this question aren't aware of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the height of the status bar provided by Apple. You need to make custom status bar or use third party navigation bar libraries.You can use [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/) or [this library](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController).